# 2 Variables for same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling to understand the following section of code as it pertains to the whole script. Can someone explain the following portion of the code to me in plain English? Why have, what looks, like 2 declared variables for the one 'Seller_No' column?

```
SET @strSellerNo2 = NULL

SELECT  @strSellerNo2 = Seller_No
FROM    Outlet.tblProductMaster
WHERE   Product_No = @strProductNo
        AND Seller_No <> @strSellerNo1
        AND Product_Status = 'Available'
```

---

```
USE [OutletRetail]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Outlet].[sp_UpdateProductStatus]    Script Date: 01/16/2014 19:58:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

--Updates Product status codes to Available if NULL
ALTER   PROCEDURE [Outlet].[sp_UpdateProductStatus]
AS

DECLARE @strProductNo varchar(20)
DECLARE @strSellerNo1 varchar(10)
DECLARE @strSellerNo2 varchar(10)


DECLARE UpdateProductCursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT Product_No, Seller_No
    FROM Outlet.tblProductMaster
    WHERE Product_Status IS NULL

OPEN UpdateProductCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateProductCursor INTO @strProduct_No, @strSellerNo1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    SET @strSellerNo2 = NULL

    SELECT  @strSellerNo2 = Seller_No
    FROM    Outlet.tblProductMaster
    WHERE   Product_No = @strProductNo
        AND Seller_No <> @strSellerNo1
        AND Product_Status = 'Available'


IF (@strSellerNo2 IS NULL)
BEGIN
        UPDATE Outlet.tblProductMaster
        SET Product_Status = 'Available'
        WHERE Product_No = @strProductNo
            AND Seller_No = @strSellerNo1
    END


UPDATE  Outlet.tblProductMaster
SET Product_Status = 'Not Available'
WHERE   Product_No = @strProductNo
        AND Seller_No <> @strSellerNo2
        AND Product_Status IS NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateProductCursor INTO @strProductNo, @strSellerNo1
END

CLOSE UpdateProductCursor
DEALLOCATE UpdateProductCursor
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps;

```
SELECT  @strSellerNo2 = Seller_No       --  Find me the Seller Number
FROM    Outlet.tblProductMaster         --  In the tblProductMaster table
WHERE   Product_No = @strProductNo      --  where the product number is the product we're looking for
    AND Seller_No <> @strSellerNo1      --  and the Seller Number is not the Seller Number previously found
    AND Product_Status = 'Available'    --  and the Product Status is "Available"
```

Comment: Can you explain why have SellerNo1 and SellerNo2 then? I'm confused by it as both seems to be pointing to the same seller_no column.

Comment: This query happens inside of a CURSOR - the CURSOR is iterating through a dataset. To give an example in a natural language; You're shopping for a car and the salesman takes you through all the cars he has on his lot. We can, at any time, call the car you are looking at Car1 and the car you looked at previously, Car2. Does that make more sense? If not, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: From the limited info I've got, it seems you have the right answer. I just can't wrap my head it.  Particulary what is happening with the below section of data since it is happening inside  a cursor.      Why set the strSellerNo2 = null and then immediately make seller_no = strSellerNo2. I can't understand the logic behind it.                                                                `SET @strSellerNo2 = NULL

    'SELECT  @strSellerNo2 = Seller_No`

Comment: Flush variable so you know it no longer contains a value (that it may contain from the CURSOR's previous cycle. There are some other things in this proc that make no sense to me though - maybe we can rewrite it more efficiently, I don't like CURSORs much anyway :) Not sure how to share details privately here, so maybe create another post?

Comment: It's my first time working with cursors and it does incur too much overhead on the system. I think the general gist of the procedure is that new products are being added to the catalog.  It looks for a product that has no status and change it to available. If there is a duplicate product then the old product becomes not available so the new product can take it's place.

Comment: The first SELECT inside the CURSOR troubles me most. It looks as if it will return multiple rows, but the value is assigned to a scalar variable.

Comment: There is a foreign key constraint for seller_no. I'm trying to undestand the code as I'm expected to add the possibility for a 'replacement' status also. That would lead to 3 status choices: available, not available and replacement. Still stuck with how to do that. Thanks so much for the free education thus far.